# "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" Android Studio with FTC Roboitcs

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm getting the "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" when I try and download the app. The following code is that I am trying to download. I have placed the file name in the AndroidManifest, or set the default program as my file. Then I tried to run the program in order to download it onto the phone. When I set the running device and clicked okay I got the fatal error listed. I need to know what it is expecting as main

`

```
private DcMotor motorRight;
private DcMotor motorLeft;
private DcMotor motorPivit;
private DcMotor motorArmExt;

public SevenTwoFourEight() {

}

@Override
public void init() {

    motorRight = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("motor_2");
    motorLeft = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("motor_1");
    motorLeft.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE);

    motorPivit = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("motor_3");
    motorArmExt = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("motor_4");
}

@Override
public void loop() {

    float left = -gamepad1.left_stick_y;
    float right = -gamepad1.right_stick_y;
    float pivit = -gamepad2.right_stick_y;
    float armExt = -gamepad2.left_stick_y;


    right = Range.clip(right, -1, 1);
    left = Range.clip(left, -1, 1);
    pivit = Range.clip(pivit, -1,1);
    armExt = Range.clip(armExt, -1, 1);

    right = (float)scaleInput(right);
    left =  (float)scaleInput(left);
    pivit = (float)scaleInput(pivit);
    armExt = (float)scaleInput(armExt);


    motorRight.setPower(right);
    motorLeft.setPower(left);
    motorPivit.setPower(pivit);
    motorArmExt.setPower(armExt);



}

@Override
public void stop() {

}


private double scaleInput(double dVal)  {
    double[] scaleArray = { 0.0, 0.05, 0.09, 0.10, 0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.24,
            0.30, 0.36, 0.43, 0.50, 0.60, 0.72, 0.85, 1.00, 1.00 };

    // get the corresponding index for the scaleInput array.
    int index = (int) (dVal * 16.0);

    // index should be positive.
    if (index < 0) {
        index = -index;
    }

    // index cannot exceed size of array minus 1.
    if (index > 16) {
        index = 16;
    }

    // get value from the array.
    double dScale;
    if (dVal < 0) {
        dScale = -scaleArray[index];
    } else {
        dScale = scaleArray[index];
    }

    // return scaled value.
    return dScale;
}
```

Here is the full error message I revived

```
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller, PID: 8439
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.K9TeleOp}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.K9TeleOp cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.K9TeleOp cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
11-10 15:21:34.208 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-10 15:26:34.388 8439-8439/com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8439 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, explain what you have tried and make your question a bit more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I have placed the file name in the AndroidManifest, or set the default program as my file. Then I tried to run the program in order to download it onto the phone. When I set the running device and clicked okay I got the fatal error listed. I need to know what it is expecting as main. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks Nick! Would be nice if you edit your question with those comments. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, added the information. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.K9TeleOp cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Comment: How would I fix that, I'm new to this. Thanks for helping

Comment: Stop trying to turn a `K9TeleOp` into an `Activity`. In fact, I don't see where you ever created an activity which would be a problem...

Comment: K9TeleOp was just another program file that I tried testing on

Comment: But you are aware you can't just put any java program onto an android phone right?

Comment: How would I make it able to download onto the phone, for it to pass the error listed.